# e.keycode is undefined in firefox 19.0.2 ,chrome 25.0.1364.172 m,IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, keycode

I want the charector to be monitored by a regular expression.

```
$('#searchContent').keyup(function(e){

        e = e || window.event;

        var patt =/\w/g;
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);


        console.log ( "key " + key + e.keycode+ " is pressed!!");

        if( e.keycode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46){ //Will return if printable char is not typed. But the datagrid will still refresh on  pressing backspace.
            console.log ( "key " + key+ e.keycode + "is about to take test!!" );
            if(!patt.test(key)){ 
                console.log ( "key " + key+e.keycode + "is failed!!");
                return;
            }
            console.log ( "key " + key +e.keycode+ "is pressed passes the test!!");
        }
        else{
            console.log ( "backspace or delete has ByPasses the conditoin!!");
        }
          //  other operations....
}
    //Result of my log. INPUT : RIS(<-backspace)
    key R undefined is pressed!! index_tab.php:173
    key R undefined is about to take test!! index_tab.php:176
    key R undefined is pressed passes the test!! index_tab.php:181
    key I undefined is pressed!! index_tab.php:173
    key I undefined is about to take test!! index_tab.php:176
    key I undefined is pressed passes the test!! index_tab.php:181
    key S undefined is pressed!! index_tab.php:173
    key S undefined is about to take test!! index_tab.php:176
    key S undefined is pressed passes the test!! index_tab.php:181
    key  undefined is pressed!! index_tab.php:173 //here backspace was pressed
    key  undefined is about to take test!! index_tab.php:176
    key  undefined is failed!!
```

Comment: Case is sensitive here, mhm.

Comment: `e.which` is normalized in jQuery, so most people use that !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, JavaScript **is** case sensitive.

`e.keycode != e.keyCode`.

And, you should use the [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)'d one - `e.keyCode`

Assuming that the `$` sign is jQuery, I'd suggest you use `e.which` when looking up codes. It has been normalized to be compatible with every browser.

See here: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/, which basically [in source is](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L449):

```
// Add which for key events
if ( event.which == null ) {
    event.which = original.charCode != null ? original.charCode : original.keyCode;
}
```

Comment: If you downvote, please provide a comment with the reason, thanks.